# Corrupted sheet objects

Tags: excel, vba, corruption, vbe

I noticed a strange behavior with Excel VBA. The Project window shows some orphaned sheet objects (e.g. "Sheet16") that cannot be deleted and don't belong to valid worksheets. Looking at these orphans, I can see that they contain callback functions from the originating worksheet (e.g."ShowCI"). A new sheet object which relates to the worksheet (e.g. "Sheet161(ShowCI)") is being created by Excel but it hasn't the callback functions which are still in the orphaned object.
I saw proposals in the web to export things into a new workbook to overcome the issue, but this is annoying (especially if to be done on files using lots of complex VBA and user forms) and doesn't really prevent from happening again.

[image]

I'm rather interested in avoiding such situations and to know from where these corruptions could result. So what causes them?

Thanx for helpful advice;-)

Regards

Comment: The `xlsm` or `xlsx` file format is known to corrupt easily especually if you have a lot of data (I had several issues over the last years, too). Save your file in the binary `xlsb` format instead of the xlm format. The binary format is known to be much more stable and results in even smaller files. Note that once a file is corrupt Excel tries to repair it but I discovered in most times the file will stay corrupt and Excel fails repairing it. The only way to repair a file properly is to start a new one and rebuild it from scratch.